# Expectation of a random functional

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are i.i.d. random variables and
let $\hat{F}_{n}$ be a random cdf that depends on $(X_{1},\ldots,X_{n})$.
For instance $\hat{F}_{n}$ could be the empirical distribution function.

Now, for a bounded real-valued function $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ consider the functional
$$
T_{\hat{F}_{n}}(X_{i}) = \int f(X_{i},t) d\hat{F}_{n}(t)
$$
Can we claim that $E\big\{ T_{\hat{F}_{n}}(X_{i}) \big\} =
E\big\{ T_{\hat{F}_{n}}(X_{j}) \big\}$ for every $1 \leq j\leq n$, $1 \leq i \leq n$?

This fact seems like it should be obviously true, but I can't really prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the functional $\hat F_n$ one is considering.

If $\hat F_n=G(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ for some symmetric functional $G$, then $(X_i,\hat F_n)$ and $(X_j,\hat F_n)$ are identically distributed hence, for every measurable functional $T$, $E(T(\hat F_n,X_i))=E(T(\hat F_n,X_j))$.

On the other hand, consider $\hat F_n=\delta_{X_1}$ the Dirac measure at $X_1$, then $\hat F_n$ is a measurable functional of $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ but $E(T(\hat F_n,X_1))=E(f(X_1,X_1))$ while $E(T(\hat F_n,X_i))=E(f(X_i,X_1))$ for every $i\ne1$, and these do not coincide in general.